# python subprocess check_output corrupts output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using yt-dlp python module to get the title of the media

```
msdos>yt-dlp --get-filename https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKuL5xaKZHM
薛之謙 Joker Xue【演員】官方完整版 MV [XKuL5xaKZHM].webm
```

but when I called it from python subprocess.check_output I got

```
cmd = ['yt-dlp', '--get-filename', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKuL5xaKZHM']
val = subprocess.check_output(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
print(val)
```

I got

```
 Joker Xue MV [XKuL5xaKZHM].webm
```

Somehow it got corrupted. But if I run and debug from vscode I got the correct output. Any idea ? I am using winpython 3.9 on windows 11

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a limitation of `yt-dlp`, where it strips characters that "should not" be part of a file name in its opinion. To read the true data, pull down the JSON using the `-J` option and parse the resulting JSON:

```
import json
import subprocess

cmd = ['yt-dlp', '-J', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKuL5xaKZHM']
val = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
val_obj = json.loads(val)
print(val_obj['title'], val_obj['id'], val_obj['ext'])
# 薛之謙 Joker Xue【演員】官方完整版 MV XKuL5xaKZHM webm
```

Pull other information out of `val_obj` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, `yt-dlp` provided the calling method in the python program, https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#embedding-yt-dlp . Depending on your needs, you could do something like this:

```py
import yt_dlp

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKuL5xaKZHM"
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    filename = ydl.prepare_filename(info)
    print(filename)
```